# WordPress Sponsors Flip Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to include this plugin on my website
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-sponsor-flip-wall/

But instead of showing it on all pages, I want to show it only on a page I will create for sponsor. Is this even possible?

As per the instructions, to include the sponsors I have to call the following function

```
<?php wp_sfw_render(); ?>
```

I have tried to include this in `footer.php` and it correctly shows the sponsors on footer.

Can I add the same code in, say `page.php` and write a condition so that it will just show for a specific page?

Comment: I want I wish I had done that already. But I haven't. So what now? Maybe some `if` can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Wordpress` template system.

You can copy a template eg: `single.php` to `sponsor.php` and follow [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) instructions.

Then when you create a page, you can select which template to use.
You can alter that template in any way that you want, including your flip wall:

```
<?php wp_sfw_render(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jure and Mihai. Looks like my theme doesn't support templates. But Thanks for your answer though

Comment: Nevermind, sorry my mistake. working now ;) http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Working_with_WordPress#Why_is_there_no_Page_Template_option_when_writing_or_editing_a_Page.3F

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom page - http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates and this code just to that page template. You then create a new page 'sponsors' and select in the right page template menu.